# Javascript debugging game not working correctly, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, debugging, dom

It's a debugging game. You use the Chrome Dev Tools to "fix" the green "start" button. Each function in the code (levelOne, levelTwo, LevelThree) makes the button unclickible. The player has to find out what's wrong with the button and make it clickable again in order to proceed. levelOne works by adding "disabled=true;" to the button, "breaking" it. The user can then use the Google Chrome Dev Tools console to toggle that off. LevelTwo changes the Id of the green button from "start" to "tart", which the player then has to restore to id="start". levelThree uses the remove() method to delete the start button from the HTML, so the user then has to re-make it in the HTML to make it re-appear. Problem: levelTwo leaves a clickable button that keeps pushing the levels up. And even if you remake the button after levelThree removes it, the button remains unclickable. REPLIT: repl.it/@drmartirosian/DEBUGGER

Comment: What _exactly_ isn't working? I click the "ENTER" button and immediately get a console error: `ReferenceError: textBox is not defined`. So, maybe start by implementing that undefined function?

Comment: You removed the link to your game. Do you have a new link you can add to your question?

Comment: Oops! Yes, here it is: https://repl.it/@drmartirosian/DEBUGGER